# What is the best way to create an objects using ModelForm in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a model for Articles in blog.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, editable=False)

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    cut_text = models.TextField(blank=True, editable=False)
    text = models.TextField()

    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
```

I want to use TextInput for Tags in admin. So I implemented ModelForm with jQuery plugin called TagManager.

```
class ArticleAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tags = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=widgets.TextInput(attrs={'name': 'tags',
                                                                           'class': 'tm-input'}))

    def clean_tags(self):
        tags = self.data.get('hidden-tags')

        clean_tags = []

        tags = [tag for tag in tags.split(',') if tags]

        for tag_name in tags:
            tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)
            tag.save()
            clean_tags.append(tag)

        return clean_tags

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('css/admin.css', 'css/tagmanager.css'),
        }

        js = ('js/jquery-2.0.3.js', 'js/tagmanager.js', 'js/admin.js')

    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

It all works very well, but now I want to know is it great idea use clean function to create model objects or there is better way to do it?

Comment: Its  not really an answer, but there is a project for doing what you are trying to achieve - django-tagging

Comment: I think your approach is good. Simple is better than complex